# Check if date falls within Month and Year range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If a user selects a range such as:

- Start: November 2016
- End: September 2017,

I want to include all results that fall within the range of 2016-11-01 to 2017-09-30.

I tried concatenating together the year, month, and day, however the issue comes that not all months have the same last day. While I know all months start on day 01, a month's end day can be 28, 29, 30, or 31.

Is there a way to do this without constructing the date? SqlServer 2008 doesn't have the EOMONTH function, and I feel like anything more complex than that is not the right solution. I would like to avoid this:

```
WHERE
    DateCol >= '2016' + '-' + '11' + '-01' AND
    DateCol <= '2017' + '-' + '09' + '-30'
```

Comment: `where date_1 >= '20161101' and date_1 <= '20170930'` -- The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2013/09/23/eomonth-equivalent-in-sql-server-2008-r2-and-below/

Comment: @SqlZim, I'm not really asking about format. The Year and Month's are selected by the user. So if they selected Sept 2017, how did you know to append 30 to the date '20170930'?

Comment: @user7733611 You don't need to know if sept has 30 or 31 days, just use `year` = 2017 and `month` = 9.

Comment: @Sami I see where you are going. I wasn't really thinking about the left side of the comparison. Lets see.

Comment: I think I answered your question.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. [`DateFromParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql). Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems to me that the easiest and best answer is to go from the first of the beginning month to the first of the month after the ending month, and make the second comparison not inclusive.

In other words, instead of this:

```
WHERE
    DateCol >= '2016' + '-' + '11' + '-01' AND
    DateCol <= '2017' + '-' + '09' + '-30'
```

simply this:

```
WHERE
    DateCol >= '2016' + '-' + '11' + '-01' AND
    DateCol < '2017' + '-' + '10' + '-01'
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I'm not sure what I would do in the case for December though. It means I would have to conditionally increment the year (and change the month from 12 to 1).

Comment: Easy to do with the `DATEADD(month,...)` function.

Comment: @Sami and why not?

Comment: @Sami The idea is that you don't have to know how many days are in the month, but if your ending month is December 2016, all you have to do is `SELECT DATEADD(Month,1,'2016-12-01')`

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking of only DATEADD'ing the month, but if you do it on the whole date (with 01 as the day), then it's smart enough to take care of the December case.

Comment: @Sami Did you try `SELECT DATEADD(Month,1,'2016-12-01')`?

Comment: All the answers for this question helped in one way or another. But this one was at the core, what solved my problem. I used this in conjunction with @Clementakis' answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster way to do so :

```
DECLARE @minDate DATE
DECLARE @maxDate DATE
SET @minDate = XXXXX
SET @maxDate =  YYYYY

-- Get the first day of the month minDate.
SET @minDate = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),@minDate,112)+'01',112)
-- Get the last day of the month minDate.
SET @maxDate = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),@maxDate,112)+'01',112)
SET @maxDate = DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, @maxDate))


SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE DateCol >= @minDate AND DateCol <= @maxDate
```

Or :

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE
WHERE DateCol >= CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),XXXXX,112)+'01',112)
  AND DateCol <= DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),YYYYY,112)+'01',112)))
```

Use syntax like CONVERT(datetime,'20170930',112) or CONVERT(datetime,'09-30-2017',110) for XXXXX and YYYYY rather than '2017-09-30' that use **SQL Server implicit convertion** from char to datetime (rely on the server configuration : can be hazardous!!!)).

Using this syntax is faster because @minDate and @maxDate do not need any evaluation. So that indexes can be used directly...

Otherwise a scalar function that will simulate the eomonth() behaviour could be usefull...

Comment: Do you mind explaining this line: CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),XXXXX,112)+'01',112) What are the 112's for?

Comment: 112 means CONVERT expect the second parameter to be an ISO text format of a date : YYYYMMDD. 110 is for the US format : MM-DD-YYYY. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp for further details...

Comment: The implicit conversion format of date to char can be checked by 'SELECT CAST(getdate() AS VACHAR(20))'. The result gives you the text format your SQL Server expect. This can vary from a machine to another, even in the same compagny...

Answer (score 0):

For 2008, you can simply convert the string

**Example**

```
Select Date1=convert(date,'November 2016')
      ,Date2=dateadd(DAY,-1,dateadd(MONTH,1,convert(date,'September 2017')))
```

**Returns**

```
Date1       Date2
2016-11-01  2017-09-30
```

So the WHERE would be somthing like this

```
 ...
 Where DateCol between convert(date,'November 2016')
                  and dateadd(DAY,-1,dateadd(MONTH,1,convert(date,'September 2017')))
```

Comment: I think the issue of the OP was the ends of months, 30 or 31 or 28.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following select statement to get last date of any month (and any year) by passing a field or date to it:

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE
SET @dtDate = '09/25/2016'
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0)) AS DATE) AS LastDay_AnyMonth
```

Please provide some example data and desired result and I will update my answer further.

Comment: I did look into this when looking for alternatives to EOMONTH. I ultimately wanted to avoid even having to figure out the last day of the month.

Comment: What is the reason you're trying to avoid figuring out the last day of the month?

Comment: I could figure it out. But logically, its irrelevant, right? Instead focus on comparing the Months and Years.

Comment: Reason I ask is because it looks like you already have dates in date format so it is easy to just convert end date to end of month date and use BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (YourData DATE);


INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
('2016-11-01'),
('2016-09-05'),
('2017-03-03'),
('2017-11-11'),
('2017-12-14'),
('2017-09-30');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT YourData
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE YEAR(YourData) =2016 AND MONTH (YourData) >= 11
    )
    SELECT YourData 
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE YEAR(YourData) =2017 AND MONTH (YourData) <= 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YourData
    FROM CTE;
```

There is no need to know the end of the month (28 or 30 or 31).

Comment: Your answer would still exclude results such as 2017-01-01

Answer (score 0):

A useful construct for performing date-based operations is to make use of a Date Dimension table. You are creating a lookup table that is populated with a lot of information about dates over a large span of time. You can then query the table based on the information that you do have. The table is small enough so that it does not impose significant performance concerns.

In your particular case, you have the month and year. You would plug that into the date dimension table to get the first of the month from the beginning month and the last of the month from the ending month. You now have a time range to search over without any complex logic or calculations on the fly.

Aaron Bertrand explains it in depth here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/